# OpenLayers 3: Find biggest cluster

Tags: openlayers, clustering

I might be able to work this out myself but I am in a bit of a deadline rush and thought about posting this here with the chance that somebody has dealt with a similar issue before.

I am using ol.source.Cluster to create themed maps. I want to show an inset map with of the biggest cluster in detail.

Answer (score 4):

I actually fuzzed out an answer rather quickly while I was thinking about the question to ask and decided to post the answer here as this might be helpful for someone else in the future.

```
var checkCluster = 0;
var clusterFeatures;
sourceCluster.forEachFeature(function (f) {
    if (f.get('features').length > checkCluster) {
        clusterFeatures = f.get('features');
        checkCluster = clusterFeatures.length;
    }
});
sourceForExtent = new ol.source.Vector();
sourceForExtent.addFeatures(clusterFeatures);
insetMap.getView().fit(
    sourceForExtent.getExtent(),
    insetMap.getSize()
);
```

[image]